# iOS Barcode Scanner for PhoneGap 2.1?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm aware of the BarcodeScanner plugin for PhoneGap 2.0 and under (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner), but has anyone seen a version (or a modified version of the one I linked to) that are compatible with PhoneGap 2.1 for iOS? I've attempted to make the changes to the code that are necessary for porting it to 2.1 (discussed here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS_plugin_signatures) but cannot get it to work.

Advice or links?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this one](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3p2)  module or library.

This is working for Me for iOS, this have also a example.

Comment: That link just leads to a number of tutorials. Can you improve your answer by explaining just what library you use, and perhaps showing how you use it with a few lines of code?

Comment: @yeah sure,.. I change "URL" plz see this one...!

Comment: This is for Android, not iOS so it doesn't help my situation at all.

Comment: If you can upgrade to PG 2.6, try this fork of the phonegap-plugin https://github.com/daynatem/Phonegap-BarcodeScanner-ios (it's noted for 2.6, and that's what it worked on for me. Perhaps it would work for 2.0)